# Slow down mp3 audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, vlc, avconv

I love VLC's option of slowing down audio playback.

Now I want to take my mp3-files to a portable player and play them there. Unfortunately the player does not have a slow down option.

How can I convert mp3s so they sound like being played slowly using VLC?

I will prefer a command line tool, but will accept other free software tools for GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend using [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) like this:

```
sox <input> <output> tempo 0.5
```

This slows down `<input>`'s tempo by a factor of 2 and record the result to `<output>`.

You can add option `--show-progress` to display relevant information and progression percentage.

Note that if `<input>` is for instance `normal.wav` and `<output>` is `half-tempo.ogg`, SoX will detect the different audio encoding by itself (for more control on that part, read `man sox`).

The `tempo` algorithm should give similar results to VLC's `scaletempo` module. However you can try the alternative `stretch` algorithm:

```
sox <input> <output> stretch 2
```

The result is expected to be more synthetic (again, read `man sox` for details) and be aware that the parameter is the inverse of the one given to `tempo` (`2` instead of `0.5` in this example).

SoX offers even more possibilities of time manipulation through `speed`, `pitch` and `bend` options that can be easily explored.

To install SoX using `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install sox
```

To enable extra codecs (including MP3), add this library:

```
sudo apt-get install libsox-fmt-all
```

As a final note, I would come back to VLC since you can play your file slowed down from command line this way:

```
cvlc --rate 0.5 <input>
```

So there may be a way to ask VLC to save the result to some file, or to output audio to JACK and then use a JACK compatible recorder.

Comment: Good solution. Note: sox don't produce mp3's so I had to subsequently use lame to convert the .wav produced with sox into an .mp3.

Comment: As explained above, it is possible to produce mp3's on Linux by enabling extra codecs.

Comment: The results using these two methods with sox sound terrible. The tempo algorithm makes speech sound warbly and underwater. The stretch algorithm sounds extremely harsh and metallic.

Answer (score 1):

The following script does this using ffmpeg.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Usage:
#   slow_down.sh infile.mp3 outfile.mp3 0.75
#   Can't slow down more than by a factor of 0.5 (limitation of ffmpeg).

if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "$0: not enough arguments"
  exit 2
fi

rm -f $2 temp.mp4
ffmpeg -i $1 -filter_complex "[0:a]atempo=$3[a]" -map "[a]"  -c:a aac temp.mp4
ffmpeg -i temp.mp4 -ar 48000 $2
rm -f temp.mp4
```

This could probably be simplified, but I wasn't able to figure out how to combine the two ffmpeg commands into one.

I found that the output of this method sounded much, much better than the results from the two algorithms provided by sox. To me it sounds about as good as the results of slowing down audio in the youtube interface.

Answer (score -1):

```
ffmpeg -i "audio.mp3" -filter:a "atempo=0.5" "output_audio.mp3"

for %f in (*.mp3) do ffmpeg -i "%f" -filter:a "atempo=0.5" "output\slow_%f"
```

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).